# Write a macro for searching string value in Column B and get the Column A value of multiple rows

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

below table i need get list of all the column A value from the column B with string as "not"

can someone help me to write macro for this.

```
ColumnA   ColumnB
A           this a A value
B           not available
C           this is C value
D           not found
E           this is E value

output:
B
D
```

Comment: You can do this with a custom filter with `contains`

Answer (score 1):

if you want a separate list, you can do it like that:

```
dim i as integer
dim lastrow as integer
lastrow = 1
do until cells(i,1).value = "" 'loop to the end of the column
    if instr(1,cells(i,2).value,"not")>0 then
        cells(lastrow,3).value = cells(i,1).value 'create list an adjacent column
        lastrow = lastrow + 1 
    end if
    i = i + 1
loop
```